# Specifying socket option on mysqli_connect

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two `mysql.sock` file.

One is at `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.

Another one is at `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`.

I want to create a connection using first mysql.sock file.

I also set the default_socket in `php.ini`.

But it always connect to second one.

The program won't be error, even if I use wrong path of `mysql.sock`.

This is my code:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "my_username";
$password = "my_password";
$database = "";
$port = "3306";
$socket = "/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $port, $socket);

//Check the host info
echo $conn->host_info."\n";

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $conn->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$conn->query("set character set utf8");

//Which socket did I connect?
$result = $conn->query("SHOW VARIABLES WHERE Variable_name = 'socket';");
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
echo $row['Value']."\n";

//Check the default_socket in php.ini file
echo ini_get("mysqli.default_socket");
?>
```

The output is:

> 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
>
> /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
>
> /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock

How to solve this problem?

Update:

```
ls -l /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

Output is

> srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0  7月 13 18:10 /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock
>
> srwxrwxrwx 1 mysql mysql 0  7月  6 21:06 /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Comment: What are you expecting the output to be? (This is a critical bit of info for pretty much any question; without it how do I know what you think your problem *is*?)

Comment: @dcsohl Sorry, I didn't explain well. I want to connect the first socket file, `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`.  I had modified `php.ini` and set default_socket to `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`. But it didn't work. It always connect to the second socket file, `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock`. If I connect correctly, the second file of output would be `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock`, right?

Comment: Have you considered that you may not be connecting through the socket at all, but through port 3306 on the loopback interface? After the `new mysqli` line, add this debug statement: `echo $conn->host_info . "\n";` And please update the question with new information (in addition to commenting). Other would-be answerers shouldn't have to read the comments for this sort of needed information.

Comment: @dcsohl Actually, I had considered about that. The program won't be error, even if I use wrong path of socket. I add `echo $conn->host_info."<br>";` after `$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database, $port, $socket);`. The output is `127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP`.

Comment: Can you please include the output of `ls -l /opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` in your question? (I suspect that one of the two is a symbolic link…)

Comment: So does the socket matter if you are connecting via TCP/IP? I'm confused as to what your **actual** goal is.

Comment: @dcsohl `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` is used by `mysql-server`, and `/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock` is used by `phpmyadmin`. I want to 
maintain database by using phpmyadmin. But I can't connect to it with php program..

Comment: @duskwuff I had updated the information, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By passing `"127.0.0.1"` as the first argument to the `mysqli` constructor, you force mysqli to connect to the MySQL server over TCP. This causes the socket argument to be ignored.

To force the connection to be made over a UNIX socket, pass `NULL` or `"localhost"` as the first argument.

Comment: It work!! Thank you very much. I had been work for this all day.