# PHP Script Connecting to MySQL Docker Container :: What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, docker, connection

I have a MySQL Docker container running, and I need a PHP script to connect to the container to do database stuff.  My script isn't working, and I can't tell if its a script thing or a container thing.

First, my system.  I'm developing on an Ubuntu 16.04.7 machine, running Docker 20.10.7, should be the latest.  My MySQL Container was pulled from Docker Hub (`docker pull mysql` pulled down Image ID 667ee8fb158e).  I spun up the container with this command:

```
docker run --detach --name=myMYSQL -p 52000:3306  --env="MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password123" 667ee8fb158e
```

Note the port mapping here.  For reasons too numerous for this post, this mapping is required.  It may be what is causing my script errors later, I dunno.

Before I discuss my script, I manually connected to the database and did some admin work:

```
mysql>
mysql> CREATE USER 'user01'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.02 sec)

mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'user01'@'localhost' = 'password123';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> create database myDB;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)

mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON myDB.* TO 'user01'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)

mysql> flush privileges;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'user01'@'localhost';
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for user01@localhost                                             |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myDB`.* TO `user01`@`localhost`                |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Okay, now for the PHP script.  After doing an `apt-get install` for `mysql-client-core-5.7` and `php-mysql`, I used the below script:

```
<?php
$servername = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "user01";
$password = "password123";
$database = "myDB";
$mysqlPort = "52000"
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database, $mysqlPort, null);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("OH NO!!!  Connection has failed, dude: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
echo "Excellent, connected successfully!!!";
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

(Note how I'm using `mysqli_connect()` here.  [According to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45080641/specifying-socket-option-on-mysqli-connect), if I'm using "127.0.0.1" as the $servername, I'm forcing a TCP connection and I don't need to supply a $socket.  That's fine with me, as I need a TCP connection here.)

Fowever, the script fails.  Here's the command line output:

```
me@myUbuntu:~$
me@myUbuntu:~$ php phpMySQL.php
PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'user01'@'10.10.10.10' (using password: YES) in /home/me/phpMySQL.php on line 8
OH NO!!!  Connection has failed, dude: Access denied for user 'user01'@'10.10.10.10' (using password: YES)me@myUbuntu:~$
```

Arrgh.  A number of Google searches imply that my script is successfully connecting to the MySQL container, but being denied?  Maybe.  Sadly, I can't enable the MySQL error logs to confirm.  But I can't help wonder if my port-mapping are coming back to bite me and the script is never successfully reaching the container?  I wish I knew.  Does anyone have any advice?  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your grant should be at 10.10.10.10.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `myDB`.* TO `user01`@`10.10.10.10`
```

Make sure that the user is also @10.10.10.10

Comment: Yes!  You are completely right, thank you!  In hindsight, I see what the trouble was; the Docker container thinks my PHP script is coming from another host... which, in a way, it is.  Once I recreated the user01 with the '10.10.10.10' IP address, everything worked fine.  Thank you!